# HTML 5 Баннер с действием

Tags: google-adwords, html, html5, javascript

Добрый день. Стоит задача сделать баннер с помощью Google Web Designer с интерактивным действием (форма).

Проблема: форму записал, действия подвесил, локально все работает. Но вот при выгрузке на Google они поверх накладывают onclick по всему телу баннера.

В Интернете не раз находили так, чтобы форма игнорировала переход и дала заполнить поля.

Кто сталкивался, что можете подсказать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился:
Если наложить сверху элемент Тапа из программы, то onClick вешаеться конкретно на Тап.
PS: Тап должен быть с "Выходом из объявления"